# Vue returning from a promise

Tags: vue.js, promise, vuejs2, vuex

I am trying to return some value from this dispatch

```
 this.$store.dispatch('setValue', this.Value)
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response)
});
```

In my vuex action I have

```
.catch(error => {
              if (error.response.status === 412) {
                return "some message"
     }
});
```

How can I pass the error back to the .vue file where the vuex dispatch is made?

Comment: Use throw error in vuex action.

}).catch((error) => {
          throw error})

Answer (score 1):

I think the correct way of doing this is to have a `status` property in your `store`.

Your status object would consist out of `error, success, loading`.

So if your action throw exception you can handle it like this:

```
catch (error) {
    commit("error", `Some Message`);
}
```

Your error mutation would look like this:

```
error(state, payload) {
    state.status.success = false;
    state.status.loading = false;
    state.status.error = payload || false;
}
```

Your template would just listen on the `store.state.status`

```
<div v-if="store.state.status.error">{{store.state.status.error}}</div>
```

I might be wrong but in my personal opinion I feel it is wrong to use actions to return stuff. Your using the store so might as well leverage it best you can.

Other extra benefits is, you can indicate to your .vue file if api is loading or when something is successful.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy a perfectly good solution, I went for something else which seemed a bit easier.

Comment: Okay awesome, I use this pattern for all of my project, works quite well so far.

Answer (score 1):

What I ended up doing was pretty simple. I chained the catch to my dispatch:

```
this.$store.dispatch('setValue', this.Value)
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response)
})
.catch(error => {
              if (error.response.status === 412) {
                return "some message"
     }
});
```

Then I returned the Axios call from the action:

```
return axios({
   method: 'post',
    url: `/mypath,
    data: mydata,
    json: true,
})
```

This means I could deal with the returned data/errors locally where I wanted to trigger an action.

Answer (score 0):

Store:

```
.catch(error => {
  if (error.response.status === 412) {
      throw error
  }
});
```

Vue element with async method:

```
try{
    let response = await this.$store.dispatch('setValue', this.Value)
} catch(error) {
    console.log(error)
});
```

Comment: Nice solution, I can see an situation where this will come in handy.